# problem to solve a non linear equation

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

```
variable[[i]]-(1/Pi)((t/2 - 1)*(Pi-2Sqrt[t-1]+2/3(t-1)^(3/2))+(-1+4/(3t)+4/(3t^2))Sqrt[(t-1)])==0
```

This is the equation but the problem is that the solution is also complex and I need only the real solution of this equation.
I try also with reduce :

```
Reduce[{variable[[3]] - 1/Pi((t/2 - 1)*(Pi-2Sqrt[t-1]+2/3(t-1)^(3/2))+(-1+4/(3t)+4/(3t^2))*Sqrt[(t-1)])==0}, 
  t, Reals]
```

and I get this error code

> Reduce::ratnz: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact 
>   coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding 
>   exact system and numericizing the result

Help me please.

Comment: Could you please post a complete minimal example ? What are `variable[[i]]`, `variable[[3]]` ?

Comment: variable[[i]] is a number taken from a table, is just a number of a table of 283 elements and i have to solve the equation (or reduce it) for all the 283 number.

Comment: Use `Rationalize[variable[[i]]]`

Comment: thanx for the answer, if i use Solve instead of Reduce, i get the solution, both Complex and Real but in any cases i can not obtain only the Real solution of the equation 
i have no idea how i can extract only the Real solution

Comment: `Solve[x^5 - 2 x^2 + 1 == 0 && x ∈ Reals, x]` -- Note `Reduce::ratnz` is a warning, not strictly an error.

Comment: thanx Michael but if i us ur method i get also in your system
Solve[x^5 - 2 x^2 + 1 == 0 && x ∈ Reals, x]

Solve::"eqf" :  "x ∈ Reals is not a well-formed equation

Comment: `code`
Solve[{variable[[3]] - 1/Pi((t/2 - 1)*(Pi-2Sqrt[t-1]+2/3(t-1)^(3/2))+(-1+4/(3t)+4/(3t^2))*Sqrt[(t-1)])==0},   t]
{{t -> -0.0930078 - 0.889984 I}, {t -> -0.0930078 + 0.889984 I}, {t ->
    1.74798- 0.829668 I}, {t -> 1.74798+ 0.829668 I}, {t -> 1.83289}}
Solve[{variable[[3]] - 1/Pi((t/2 - 1)*(Pi-2Sqrt[t-1]+2/3(t-1)^(3/2))+(-1+4/(3t)+4/(3t^2))*Sqrt[(t-1)])==0},   t, Reals]
{}

If i try to solve the eqn i get all the solution (Reals and COmplex), if i impose Reals i get a empty answer why?